# AWS kubernetes connection reset after 11 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, java-io, sqlexception

When performing a jdbc connection and the transaction taking longer than 11 minutes, connection reset occurs in the Kubernetes, AWS spring boot Java application.

The same Spring boot program, when launched from on-perm, functions well.

Due to the DB's continued on-premises operation, there was already a latency issue.

Find the below error

> WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 -
> Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@54ef7 marked as broken
> because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset WARN
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17002,
> SQLState: 08006 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
>
> - IO Error: Connection reset Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset

Our program tries to retrieve more substantial data from the database and write it to binary file.

Comment: is your spring boot Java application behind some gateway/load-balancer?

Comment: Yes ,  but its for acessing the application

Comment: Then you need to double check your gateway's configuration. It is possible that your gateway has a connection timeout setting.

Comment: checked , nothing wrong with gateways

Answer (score 0):

when retrieving bigger amounts of data, the connection remains open without transmitting any information (often because the DB is still busy). The problem is caused by NAT-GATEWAY. nat-gateway on AWS terminates any connection with no data after 350 seconds.

Two solutions

1. Change the default TCP behavior in the kernel
2. Change the jdbc connector settings

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout

jdbc settings:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html